# Is there a way to extend the Hibernate Entity Manager?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate OGM JPA with MongoDB. The problem I am trying to solve is adding operation retry logic to the find, persist, query, remove methods in a JPA environment. The underlying data source driver is the mongodb driver. We are experiencing the driver throwing network exceptions if we are connected to the primary member of replica set and that primary goes down. We need to retry the operation when our applications get a network exception, however, I want to be able to make this retry logic part of the EntityManager so all of our applications will not have to incorporate this boiler plate code. I have not seen anything that specifically says that extending the Hibernate Entity Manager is possible. The hibernate bootstrap process seems like it may allow me to do this, however, I am not sure. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and guide me to some resources/examples that I can look at?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not composing hibernate into a higher-level service? For retries, you can use [resilience4j](http://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/#_retry). Integrating r4j into EntityManager seems like it would be harder than _wrapping_ EntityManager with the desired functionality. r4j features max attempt count, fixed or randomized delay between attempts, exponential backoff, etc. Exponential backoff can help in your situation (network partition). Since failover is not instantaneous, there's no point in hammering a down service in a tight loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I cannot incorporate any new products/libraries into our system at this time. Secondly, it looks like in order to use this, all of our applications will have to implement this. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you wrap the call with a utility method, which adds the retry logic? So, replace `entityMgr.persist(transient)` with `Retrier.execute(3, () -> entityMgr.persist(tranisent))`. `Retrier` is your own code, not from a lib. Adding `Retrier` is simpler, I'd guess, than adding a hibernate extension. Either way, you're adding something.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is something you really want. For example, the app is doing some logic that comprises two updates and one insert. These three are wrapped in a transaction. If the insert fails, you need to roll back the _entire_ logic and start a new transaction from scratch. Retrying just `entityMgr.persist(transient)` is not going to help you at all.

Comment: Using the wrapper solution would require all of our applications changing to incorporate the 'Retrier', which I would prefer not to do. Also, as far as the transaction is concerned, I think doing an initial retry should not be an issue, because if the retries fail, rolling back the entire logic and start a new transaction should still work.

Comment: Doing a retry in the middle of a txn would definitely _not_ work. In your scenario, the network is the issue. So, the retry would use a _different_ jdbc connection. All the work done using the old connection (which died and triggered the retry) is lost.

Comment: The scenario that we are experiencing has to do with the MongoDB driver that we are using. When the driver is trying to connect to the primary as it is going down, the driver is using an already opened connection to do a read operation. The read operation is blocking and timing out after 15 minutes. In order for the driver not to block, we use the socketTimeout property for the driver that will timeout after 5 second, then we want to do the retry.

Comment: I am experimenting using a custom extended version of the MongoDBDialect class that will do the retries. When the driver's cluster topology is updated with the new primary, then the connection is re-established and the operation is successful. I have been testing this scenario and it seems to be working. Are you saying that if the retries fail and never get a new connection then the transaction rollback won't work? Can you explain?

Comment: The official mongdb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-retry) says: "The individual write operations inside the transaction are not retryable". For example, say a database transaction comprises write operations A, B, and then C. The _entire_ transaction must happen using _one_ connection. If the server goes down on operation C, then it is wrong to create a new connection and retry just operation C. The app has to retry the _entire_ transaction with _all_ the writes (A, B, and C). This is why the doc examples wrap the whole txn with `while`.

Comment: I viewed the document and assuming you are referring to the example in the runTransactionWithRetry() method specified in the Transactions in Applications 'Retry Transaction' section. The transactions that are referred to in this documentation is for MongoDB 4.0. We are using MongoDB 3.6 which does not support this. Also, I understand about the entire transaction must happen using one connection, but how does the MongoDB driver know to use the same connection? When a call to the MongoDB driver is made it gets the connection from a connection pool, and it is not guaranteed to use the same.

Comment: "it is not guaranteed to use the same" . . . Right! This is why you cannot retry from step 4 in a multi-step transaction. You have to rollback _everything_ and retry from step _1_. Retrying _everything_ is the _only_ way to ensure _all_ steps in the transaction use the _same_ connection.